# Client Server Application with SigmaJS in Java

Tags: java, client-server, sigma.js

I want to make a client/server application with SigmaJS in Java. I make the server file which create the JSON file. Do you known how can I "call" SigmaJS application with the JSON file to create the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look at this example : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/load-external-json.html ?